# SharePoint Threshold Limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, list-view-threshold

We have a sharepoint list with 6.5k items. we have created 4 separate views using indexed columns as filters. All 4 separate views have less than 2k items each. One of the 4 views can be exported to excel, the other three return the threshold error message. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have done related tests, I created 5k+ items in a list which exceeded the limit, however the data can still be exported normally.
[image]

I have encountered a similar thread before. One way you could try is to create a new view from the existing view to see if it works.

Please refer to this post:
[Excel fails to download SharePoint List data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/145061/excel-fails-to-download-sharepoint-list-data.html)